# Lankit Datatables Bundle in Symfony2

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, datatables, twig

I have a little problem with a backoffice implementation for Symfony, I want to print some info in different tables and I want to filter them with Datatables system. I code all perfectly but when I go to the view that the info would be printed it doens't print anything and give me an 500 error, the thead and tfoot prints but the tbody doens't.

Here are the code:

Routing:

```
backoffice_view:
    path: /backoffice/table
    defaults: { _controller: ApiBundle:Api:view }

backoffice_table_info:
    path: /backoffice/table/info
    defaults: { _controller: ApiBundle:Api:table }
    requirements:
        _method: GET
```

Controller:

```
public function tableAction() {

    $datatable = $this->get('lankit_datatables')->getDatatable('ApiBundle:Entity');

    return $datatable->getSearchResults();


}

public function viewAction() {

    return $this->render('ApiBundle:Api:table.html.twig', array(

    ));

}
```

Javascript for the table (I get the code to filter in each column):

```
$('#table tfoot th').each( function () {
     var title = $(this).text();
     $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Busca en '+title+'" />' );
 } );

var tablas = $('#table').DataTable( {
    "language": {   
         "aria": {
                "sortAscending": ": activate to sort column ascending",
                "sortDescending": ": activate to sort column descending"
         },
         "emptyTable": "No data available in table",
         "info": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ records",
         "infoEmpty": "No records found",
         "infoFiltered": "(filtered1 from _MAX_ total records)",
         "lengthMenu": "Show _MENU_",
         "search": "Search:",
         "zeroRecords": "No matching records found",
         "paginate": {
             "previous":"Prev",
             "next": "Next",
             "last": "Last",
             "first": "First"
         }
    },

    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "../table/info",

    "aoColumns": [
        { "mData": "data1"},
        { "mData": "data2"},
        { "mData": "data3"},
        { "mData": "data4"},
        { "mData": "data5"},
        { "mData": "data6"}
    ],

    "lengthMenu": [
        [5, 15, 20, -1],
        [5, 15, 20, "All"] // change per page values here
    ],
    // set the initial value
    "pageLength": 15,            
    "pagingType": "bootstrap_full_number",
    "order": [
        [2, "asc"]
    ] // set first column as a default sort by asc

});

// Apply the search
tablas.columns().every( function () {
    var that = this;
    $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
        if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
            that
                .search( this.value )
                .draw();
        }
    } );
} );
```

Twig:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-checkable order-column table-header-fixed" id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Data1</th>
            <th>Data2</th>
            <th>Data3</th>
            <th>Data4</th>
            <th>Data5</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
       <tr>
           <th>Data1</th>
           <th>Data2</th>
           <th>Data3</th>
           <th>Data4</th>
           <th>Data5</th>
       </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
       <tr>

       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I don't know if it's a problem that I need a Special Repository for that Entity or something with the javascript code.

Thanks in advance for all the answers :)
Carl

EDIT:
Apache Error Log:

```
[Thu Jul 28 13:29:38.560587 2016] [:error] [pid 8624:tid 1880] [client   ::1:60679] PHP Fatal error: Class  'Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\SaveSessionListener' not found in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\api\\app\\cache\\prod\\classes.php on line 1837, referer: http://localhost/api/web/app_dev.php/backoffice/table
[Thu Jul 28 13:29:38.561087 2016] [:error] [pid 8624:tid 1864] [client ::1:60685] PHP Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\SaveSessionListener' not found in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\api\\app\\cache\\prod\\classes.php on line 1837, referer: http://localhost/api/web/app_dev.php/backoffice/table
[Thu Jul 28 13:29:38.561087 2016] [:error] [pid 8624:tid 1880] [client ::1:60679] PHP Stack trace:, referer: http://localhost/api/web/app_dev.php/backoffice/table
[Thu Jul 28 13:29:38.561087 2016] [:error] [pid 8624:tid 1864] [client ::1:60685] PHP Stack trace:, referer: http://localhost/api/web/app_dev.php/backoffice/table
[Thu Jul 28 13:29:38.561087 2016] [:error] [pid 8624:tid 1880] [client ::1:60679] PHP 1. {main}() C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\api\\web\\app.php:0, referer: http://localhost/api/web/app_dev.php/backoffice/table
[Thu Jul 28 13:29:38.561087 2016] [:error] [pid 8624:tid 1864] [client ::1:60685] PHP 1. {main}() C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\api\\web\\app.php:0, referer: http://localhost/api/web/app_dev.php/backoffice/table
[Thu Jul 28 13:29:38.561587 2016] [:error] [pid 8624:tid 1864] [client ::1:60685] PHP 2. Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel->handle() C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\api\\web\\app.php:27, referer: http://localhost/api/web/app_dev.php/backoffice/table
[Thu Jul 28 13:29:38.561587 2016] [:error] [pid 8624:tid 1880] [client ::1:60679] PHP 2. Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel->handle() C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\api\\web\\app.php:27, referer: http://localhost/api/web/app_dev.php/backoffice/table
[Thu Jul 28 13:29:38.561587 2016] [:error] [pid 8624:tid 1864] [client ::1:60685] PHP 3. Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel->getHttpKernel() C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\api\\app\\bootstrap.php.cache:2336, referer: http://localhost/api/web/app_dev.php/backoffice/table
[Thu Jul 28 13:29:38.561587 2016] [:error] [pid 8624:tid 1880] [client ::1:60679] PHP 3. Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel->getHttpKernel() C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\api\\app\\bootstrap.php.cache:2336, referer: http://localhost/api/web/app_dev.php/backoffice/table
[Thu Jul 28 13:29:38.561587 2016] [:error] [pid 8624:tid 1864] [client ::1:60685] PHP 4. Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container->get() C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\api\\app\\bootstrap.php.cache:2340, referer: http://localhost/api/web/app_dev.php/backoffice/table
[Thu Jul 28 13:29:38.561587 2016] [:error] [pid 8624:tid 1880] [client ::1:60679] PHP 4. Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container->get() C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\api\\app\\bootstrap.php.cache:2340, referer: http://localhost/api/web/app_dev.php/backoffice/table
[Thu Jul 28 13:29:38.561587 2016] [:error] [pid 8624:tid 1864] [client ::1:60685] PHP 5. appProdProjectContainer->getHttpKernelService() C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\api\\app\\bootstrap.php.cache:2062, referer: http://localhost/api/web/app_dev.php/backoffice/table
[Thu Jul 28 13:29:38.561587 2016] [:error] [pid 8624:tid 1880] [client ::1:60679] PHP 5. appProdProjectContainer->getHttpKernelService() C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\api\\app\\bootstrap.php.cache:2062, referer: http://localhost/api/web/app_dev.php/backoffice/table
[Thu Jul 28 13:29:38.562087 2016] [:error] [pid 8624:tid 1864] [client ::1:60685] PHP 6. Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container->get() C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\api\\app\\cache\\prod\\appProdProjectContainer.php:657, referer: http://localhost/api/web/app_dev.php/backoffice/table
[Thu Jul 28 13:29:38.562087 2016] [:error] [pid 8624:tid 1864] [client ::1:60685] PHP 7. appProdProjectContainer->getEventDispatcherService() C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\api\\app\\bootstrap.php.cache:2062, referer: http://localhost/api/web/app_dev.php/backoffice/table
[Thu Jul 28 13:29:38.562087 2016] [:error] [pid 8624:tid 1880] [client ::1:60679] PHP 6. Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container->get() C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\api\\app\\cache\\prod\\appProdProjectContainer.php:657, referer: http://localhost/api/web/app_dev.php/backoffice/table
[Thu Jul 28 13:29:38.562087 2016] [:error] [pid 8624:tid 1864] [client ::1:60685] PHP 8. Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->addSubscriberService() C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\api\\app\\cache\\prod\\appProdProjectContainer.php:425, referer: http://localhost/api/web/app_dev.php/backoffice/historial
[Thu Jul 28 13:29:38.562087 2016] [:error] [pid 8624:tid 1880] [client ::1:60679] PHP 7. appProdProjectContainer->getEventDispatcherService() C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\api\\app\\bootstrap.php.cache:2062, referer: http://localhost/api/web/app_dev.php/backoffice/historial
[Thu Jul 28 13:29:38.562087 2016] [:error] [pid 8624:tid 1880] [client ::1:60679] PHP 8. Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->addSubscriberService() C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\api\\app\\cache\\prod\\appProdProjectContainer.php:425, referer: http://localhost/api/web/app_dev.php/backoffice/historial
[Thu Jul 28 13:29:39.022904 2016] [:error] [pid 8624:tid 1864] [client ::1:60685] PHP Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\SaveSessionListener' not found in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\api\\app\\cache\\prod\\classes.php on line 1837, referer: http://localhost/api/web/metronic/css/plugins-md.min.css
[Thu Jul 28 13:29:39.022904 2016] [:error] [pid 8624:tid 1864] [client ::1:60685] PHP Stack trace:, referer: http://localhost/api/web/metronic/css/plugins-md.min.css
[Thu Jul 28 13:29:39.023406 2016] [:error] [pid 8624:tid 1864] [client ::1:60685] PHP 1. {main}() C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\api\\web\\app.php:0, referer: http://localhost/api/web/metronic/css/plugins-md.min.css
[Thu Jul 28 13:29:39.023406 2016] [:error] [pid 8624:tid 1864] [client ::1:60685] PHP 2. Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel->handle() C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\api\\web\\app.php:27, referer: http://localhost/api/web/metronic/css/plugins-md.min.css
[Thu Jul 28 13:29:39.023406 2016] [:error] [pid 8624:tid 1864] [client ::1:60685] PHP 3. Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel->getHttpKernel() C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\api\\app\\bootstrap.php.cache:2336, referer: http://localhost/api/web/metronic/css/plugins-md.min.css
[Thu Jul 28 13:29:39.023906 2016] [:error] [pid 8624:tid 1864] [client ::1:60685] PHP 4. Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container->get() C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\api\\app\\bootstrap.php.cache:2340, referer: http://localhost/api/web/metronic/css/plugins-md.min.css
[Thu Jul 28 13:29:39.023906 2016] [:error] [pid 8624:tid 1864] [client ::1:60685] PHP 5. appProdProjectContainer->getHttpKernelService() C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\api\\app\\bootstrap.php.cache:2062, referer: http://localhost/api/web/metronic/css/plugins-md.min.css
[Thu Jul 28 13:29:39.023906 2016] [:error] [pid 8624:tid 1864] [client ::1:60685] PHP 6. Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container->get() C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\api\\app\\cache\\prod\\appProdProjectContainer.php:657, referer: http://localhost/api/web/metronic/css/plugins-md.min.css
[Thu Jul 28 13:29:39.024407 2016] [:error] [pid 8624:tid 1864] [client ::1:60685] PHP 7. appProdProjectContainer->getEventDispatcherService() C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\api\\app\\bootstrap.php.cache:2062, referer: http://localhost/api/web/metronic/css/plugins-md.min.css
[Thu Jul 28 13:29:39.024407 2016] [:error] [pid 8624:tid 1864] [client ::1:60685] PHP 8. Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->addSubscriberService() C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\api\\app\\cache\\prod\\appProdProjectContainer.php:425, referer: http://localhost/api/web/metronic/css/plugins-md.min.css
```

the problem is: when I pass the Entity in the controller It doens't respond me anything and I think it's problem from the serializer.

Comment: Can you post the Apache/Nginx error log?

Comment: There you are @PietervandenHam

Comment: Can you post the symfony dev.log

Answer (score 0):

I found a posible solution comenting in Database.php from the bundle in Line 359

```
//$fieldName = Container::camelize($fieldName);
```

It worked for now and it prints and filter everything inside the table.